# Set lim inf and lim sup question.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

If $A_n = \{m/n : m \in N\}, n \in N$. What is $\lim \inf_n$ $A_n$ and $\lim\sup_n$ $A_n$?

Using the definitions:

$\lim \inf A_n = \bigcup\limits_{n\in N}\bigcap\limits_{k > n} m/n = \bigcup\limits_{n\in N}0 = 0$

$\lim \sup A_n =\bigcap\limits_{n\in N}\bigcup\limits_{k > n}
\frac{m}{n} = \bigcup\limits_{n\in N} \frac{m}{n}= 0$

I am trouble thinking of the intersections and unions. For instance $\bigcap\limits_{k > n}$ $\frac{m}{n}$ is the intersection of $\{\frac{m}{n},\frac{m}{n+1},\frac{m}{n+2},....\}$ I see how this eventually approaches $0$, but this is the intersection of a bunch of points instead of sets? Essentially the union and intersection operations don't make much sense to me in this context because I'm dealing with points instead of sets, but I don't know how else to approach the problem.

Comment: This isn't the definition. Of course, there is no such thing as intersection of points. Visit Wikipedia's "Limit superior and limit inferior".

Comment: Wikipedia uses the same definition of lim sup and lim inf as I've used in "Special case: Discrete Metric". I understand that an intersection of points makes no sense, hence my thinking that I've misinterpreted a key concept and was hoping someone could clarify in the context of the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\cup_n\cap_k A_k$?

Comment: That's right. However, doesn't all that do is just make m/n, m/k and the same issue I have persists?

Comment: As a first step, can you figure out what $\cap_{k>17}A_k$ is? and what $\cup_{k>17}A_k$ is?

Comment: Oh. I see is the interpretation that $A_17$ = {m/17} as m varies over the natural numbers so it's a set of the form {1/17,2/17....}, and $A_18$ = {1/18,2/18,3/18,....}. So forth...The only number in common would be $0$ which it eventually approaches. So $\cap A_k$ = $0$ and for $\cup A_k$ it would be all rational numbers?

Comment: No,  ∩Ak is not 0, please stop confusing elements and sets.

Comment: Sorry the { } got hidden in the formatting.$\{0\}$ for $\cap Ak$ and non-negative rational numbers for $\cup Ak$?

Comment: Is 42 in $A_{17}$?

Comment: Yes.I think I figured it out now.

Comment: Good. Then let me encourage you to write up a solution, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Are you still there, Eddie?

Comment: Yes, I am still around.

Answer (score 2):

lim sup$_n$ $A_n$ = $\mathbb{Q}$.To see let $x \in$ lim sup$_n$ $A_n$. Then $x = \frac{m_n}{n}$ for infinitely many $n$, so $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, thus lim sup$_n$ $A_n$ $\subset \mathbb{Q}$.

Now let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. So $x = \frac{m}{n}$ for integers $m$ and $n \neq 0$. This means $x = \frac{cm}{cn}$ for $c \geq 1$, so $x \in$ lim sup$_n$ $A_n$. Thus $\mathbb{Q} \subset$ lim sup$_n$ $A_n$. So lim sup$_n$ $A_n$ = $\mathbb{Q}$.

lim inf$_n$ $A_n$ = $\mathbb{N}$.

lim inf$_n$ $A_n$ = $\{xn \in \mathbb{N}\}$, so $\mathbb{N} \subset$ lim inf$_n$ $A_n$.

To see the reverse direction, we use the fact lim inf$_n$ $A_n$ $\subset$ lim sup$_n$ 
 $A_n$.

So for  $x \in$ lim inf$_n$ $A_n$ $\subset$ lim sup$_n$ 
 $A_n$ = $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $x = \frac{p}{q}$ for natural numbers $p$ and $q$. Since $x$ is in $A_n$ let's say for $n \geq n_0$, choose a $n_1 > n_0$, so $n_1 \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, $(n_1 + 1)\frac{p}{q} = n_1 \frac{p}{q} + \frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $n_1 \frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{N} $, $\frac{p}{q}$ must also be in $\mathbb{N}$ in order for their sum to be in $\mathbb{N}$. Thus $x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{N}$ completing the proof.